# WPF – Keep Trigger If Corresponding Property Is Set

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to keep the `Trigger` within `Style` if the corresponding property is set outside the `Style`?

The second `Button` works fine, but the `Trigger` does not work on the first one `Button`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="GreenYellow" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Foreground="Orange">The First Button</Button>
    <Button>The Second Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your default value in the `Style`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button>The First Button</Button>
    <Button>The Second Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Have a look at the **Dependency Property Setting Precedence List** on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

If you want to make it dynamic. You have to write your own `CustomButton` with a additional `DependencyProperty` and write your own `Style` for it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is that local dependency property values takes precedence over property values set by setters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx.

So no, it is not possible to use a `Setter` in a `Style` to set a property that has been set to a local value:

```
<Button Foreground="Orange">The First Button</Button>
```